# Как получить правильно данные и обработать их (Alamofire + php). Проблема с русскими символами

Tags: php, swift, alamofire

Подскажите как правильно получить данные и их обработать?
Вот код php на сервере:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8');
    $arr = array( "data" => array('team' => 'привет', 
        'date' => '4.01.2019',
        'content' => 'Всем привет данные получены'
        ));
$json = json_encode($arr, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);
// $fp = fopen('php://output', 'w');
// fwrite($fp, $json); 
// fclose($fp);
echo $json;

?>
```

Вот код на Свифте:

```
Alamofire.request("https://mp3cloud.ru/test/get.php").responseJSON
            { response in
                guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                    return
                }

                guard let JSON = response.result.value else {
                        print("bad")
                        return
                }
            print(JSON)
```

В итоге в консоль выводиться:

```
{
    data =     {
        content = "\U0412\U0441\U0435\U043c \U043f\U0440\U0438\U0432\U0435\U0442 \U0434\U0430\U043d\U043d\U044b\U0435 \U043f\U043e\U043b\U0443\U0447\U0435\U043d\U044b";
        date = "4.01.2019";
        team = "\U043f\U0440\U0438\U0432\U0435\U0442";
    };
}
```

С ног уже сбился. Вроде все просто должно быть.
Что я делаю не так и как мне получить данные с которыми удобно работать?
Вид данных было бы неплохо Data["date"] или подобное.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте в Podfile:

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 4.0'
```

И выполните "pod install" для установки SwiftyJSON.

В начало файла добавьте:

```
import SwiftyJSON
```

Поменяйте код на:

```
Alamofire.request("https://mp3cloud.ru/test/get.php").responseJSON
        { response in
            guard response.result.isSuccess else {
                return
            }
            guard let json = response.result.value else {
                print("bad")
                return
            }
            if let data = response.data {
                do {
                    let json = try JSON(data: data)
                    print(json)
                    print(json["data"]["team"])
                    print(json["data"]["date"])
                } catch {
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Без импорта дополнительных библиотек никак не обойтись? Хотелось бы обработку организовать средствами Свифта.

Comment: @ПетровКирилл Только если каждое поле обрабатывать функцией декодирования строки. Это заметно больше кода, чем использование готовой библиотеки.

Comment: Так же вы можете посмотреть как реализовано декодирование в SwiftyJSON и повторить его у себя в коде: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/blob/master/Source/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.swift